# NHibernate: Criteria/SubCriteria Projection

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a class Mod, which has a member:

```
ICollection<Event> EventList
```

The class Event has a member:

```
public virtual EventType Type { get; set; }
```

The class EvenType has member:

```
   public virtual int Id
```

I want to get a list of all Events in Mod which have an id of 1 or 2 using NHibernate Criteria. I did this:

```
var subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Mod>()
    .Add(Restrictions.In("Event.Type", new int[] {1, 2 })
    );
criteria.Add(Subqueries.Exists(subCriteria));
```

but I get a runtime error saying
Cannot use subqueries on a criteria without a projection.

So, fine, but I don't know what to put for the Projection. I can find examples of how to do Projections, but nothing that really explains the purpose. I've tried various things, but all result in a runtime error:

*Message : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
Source : mscorlib
Help link :
ParamName : key*

I need to use subquery because I will be adding more when this works.

Can you suggest what to do for Projection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As documented here: [16.4. Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-associations) it could be done like this:

```
IQueryOver<Mod, Event> query = session
  .QueryOver<Mod>()
  .JoinQueryOver<Event>(mod => mod.EventList)
  .WhereRestrictionOn(evnt => evnt.Type.Id).IsIn(new object[] { 1, 2});

var result = query.List<Mod>();
```

EDIT: pure Criteria API:

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Mod>();
var sub = criteria.CreateCriteria("EventList", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
    sub.Add(new InExpression("Type", new object[] { 1, 2 }));

var result = criteria.List<Mod>();
```

using detached criteria. In this case, the `EventType` must have property `ModId` or refernece to the `Mod` instance. In the subquery, we have to return list of valid Mod.IDs

```
var sub = DetachedCriteria
 .For<Event>()
 .Add(Restrictions.In("Type", new int[] {1, 2 })) // WHERE
 .SetProjection(Projections.Property("ModId")); // Mod.ID the SELECT clause

var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Mod>();
criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ID", sub)); // Mod.ID in (select
var result = criteria.List<Mod>();
```

Comment: Radim, Thank you for your response. I do need to use a criteria query, though.

Comment: QueryOver is on top of Criteria API... *"QueryOver api, which combines the use of Extension Methods and Lambda Expressions .. to provide a statically typesafe wrapper round the ICriteria API"*

Comment: Again, I thank you. My question is about Projections. I already have a criteria instance, so I cannot create another one as in your second example, or at least that criteria will have to be added to the existing.

Comment: I edited the answer, with information how to solve the Projections issue. You will need `ModId` to be available on `EventType`... to fulfill the IN clause

Comment: I did learn from you that there is more than one way to accomplish this. I had to do this a certain way in order to be consistent with the existing code, but knowing other ways is good.